# I need the details section to suppress if a custom date field is blank in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, error-suppression, suppression

I have the following suppression formula in the details section:

{JCJM.udRough} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#
AND
{JCJM.udTrim} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#

and it works. However, I also need it to suppress if the udRough or udTrim field is blank. When I try to add

OR {JCJM.udRough}=""

it says that a date-time is expected where the blank quotes are. 
Can someone please help?

Comment: Update: The new suppression formula is as follows, but it does not suppress the section if the field is blank:

{JCJM.udRough} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#
AND
{JCJM.udTrim} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#
OR
isNull({JCJM.udRough})
AND
isNull({JCJM.udTrim})

Comment: I have now also tried the following in the details suppress formula to no avail:

{JCJM.udRough} <= #1/1/2013 12:00# OR isNull({JCJM.udRough})
AND
{JCJM.udTrim} <= #1/1/2013 12:00# OR isNull({JCJM.udTrim})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule in CR, if a field can be null then you should explicitly check for that case *first* in a formula, otherwise it will not evaluate properly. Otherwise, CR will treat it like an unhandled exception.

So in your case, CR is short-circuit evaluating the expression `{JCJM.udRough}<=#1/1/2013 12:00#` as the very first thing, sees that the field is null, and stops evaluating the rest of the formula since it has encountered an exception.

What you need is:

`(isnull({JCJM.udRough}) or {JCJM.udRough} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#) 
 and (isnull({JCJM.udTrim}) or {JCJM.udTrim} <= #1/1/2013 12:00#)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ISNULL({JCJM.udRough})
Then true
else false
```

This is from my understanding from your question if you are searching for something different let me know will try to answer it.